# Webpack serves only half the file

Tags: webpack

I have a webpack-dev-server running and it serves randomly only parts of the bundle files (main.js and vendor.js). When I reload in both chrome or firefox it's loading 5MB of the file in the first try and then 3MB in the second try. It does not finish the request. After long waiting, I receive the error ERR_CONNECTION_RESET. Webpack does not log any errors.

I have also tried cleaning my npm cache. I have the same npm and node version as my colleagues have (npm: v5.0.3, node: 8.1.2). It must be a webpack problem or something environmental related.

This must be an environment problem since it's working fine for everyone but me.
Here's are our plugins in webpack.config.js and some other parts:

```
let plugins = [
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        name: 'vendor',
        minChunks(module, count) {
            let context = module.context;
            return context && context.indexOf('node_modules') >= 0;
        }
    }),
    //catch all - anything used in more than one place
    new CommonsChunkPlugin({
        async: 'commons',
        minChunks(module, count) {
            return count >= 2;
        }
    }),

    new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        'process.env': {
            'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(nodeEnvString)
        }
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
        sourceMap: true
    }),
    new CopyWebpackPlugins([
        {
            from: 'src/res',
            to: ''
        }
    ])
];
plugins.unshift(new webpack.NamedModulesPlugin());
plugins.unshift(new webpack.NoEmitOnErrorsPlugin());
plugins.unshift(new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin());

entries = [
    'react-hot-loader/patch',
    'webpack-dev-server/client?' + (useHttps ? 'https' : 'http') + '://localhost:' + PORT,
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './src/index'
];

module.exporst = {
    ...
    devServer: {
        inline: true,
        hot: true,
        https: useHttps,
        contentBase: './src/res',
        port: PORT,
        historyApiFallback: true
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.jsx?$/,
                use: [
                    'babel-loader',
                    'eslint-loader'
                ],
                include: [
                    PATH.resolve(__dirname, 'src'), \/lib\//
                ]
            },
        ]
    },
    ...
};
```

Comment: Do you have an antivirus?

Comment: @veksen yeah i have bitdefender installed

Comment: @veksen thanks for the hint. Disabled protection and it's working like a charm. You solved it!